# Can't pass data to controller; why doesn't it work?

Tags: ios, objective-c, viewcontroller

I see another question and study that,
but can't pass data.

This is my code.

1. in HomeViewController.h

   ```
   @protocol homeViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
   -(void)addItemViewController:(Float32)item;
   @end
   ```

   @interface HomeViewController : UIViewController 
   @property (nonatomic,retain) id delegate;
2. in HomeViewController.mm

   ```
   #import "HomeViewController.h"
       static HomeViewController *mainController = nil; 

   #pragma mark MAIN CALLBACK
   void monoAudioCallback( Float32 * buffer, UInt32 frameSize, void * userData )
   {
       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
               [homeOsciView setDataMaxValue:fftMaxVal minValue:0]; 
               [homeOsciView addAndDrawData:fftData lenght:length];
               if(fftMaxVal >=0){
               [mainController.delegate addItemViewController:fftMaxVal];
                }
              [homeOsciView addAndDrawUILabelHz: HZ];
            });
   }
       viewDidLoad{
        mainController = self;
    }
   ```
3. in graphViewController.h

   ```
   @interface GraphViewController : UIViewController<homeViewControllerDelegate>
   -(void)addItemViewController:(Float32)item;
   ```
4. in graphViewController.m

   ```
       viewDidLoad(){
       homevc = [[HomeViewController alloc]init];
               homevc.delegate = self;
   }

       -(void)addItemViewController:(Float32)item{
           self.testdata = item;
           printf("thisis graphView data : %f\n",self.testdata);
       }
   ```

I want to draw graph that HomeViewController passed data to graphViewController, but this code does not give an error but does not work either.

i don't know problem.

Can you help me?

Comment: By the way, delegate should be `weak` instead of `retain` I believe :D Does your `addItemViewController` method get called ?

Comment: Unable to understand the issue. Show complete classes of HomeViewController and GraphViewController in one sequence.

Comment: @Zhang Yes  look 2-1 line 5 called. [mainController.delegate addItemViewController: fftMaxVal];]

Comment: @Shoaib you want complete code?

Comment: @JisooKwon, Just I want to see the complete flow of the code so post the sequence of the code as much as you can.

Comment: @Shoaib ok I edit my post

Comment: Uh ok, so line 5 in code block 2-1 is reached in your program execution but the actual method `addItemViewController` didn't execute, i.e. you're not seeing `printf("thisis graphView data : %f\n",self.testdata);` getting called ? Sounds like a delegate issue. You initialised `mainController` with `nil`, is `mainController` NOT nil when this line `[mainController.delegate addItemViewController:fftMaxVal];` gets called? I mean, do you have this line of code somewhere: `mainController = [[HomeController alloc] init];` ?

Comment: @Zhang Yes i think too.. but i don't know solve this issue..do you know??

Comment: @Zhang Yes see 2 HomeViewController.m
last line mainController = self;
and viewDidLoad in graphViewController exist too.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self init];
}
-(void)init{
    self = [super init];
    if(self){
        homevc = [[HomeViewController alloc]init];
        homevc.delegate = self;
    }
}

Comment: Perhaps you're building an app about Houses/Homes and want to graph the results of prices but either way, I think you're confused about your HomeViewController naming altogether. It appears you've declared a variable of type `HomeViewController` inside your `HomeViewController` and set that variable to point back to HomeViewController itself....which is redundant...

Comment: @Zhang Yes Thank you i'll try that!!!

Comment: @JisooKwon Are you using `UIStoryboard` or `xib` ? if you use `xib (nib)` than alloc  using This method `initWithNibName`. OR use to `storybordwithIdentifier` method  to alloc the `viewcontroller`.

Comment: @ilesh i using UIStoryboard!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to ensure you're understanding my comments, I wrote you a demo app of an example delegate process.

### AppDelegate.m

```
#import "GraphViewController.h"

@interface AppDelegate ()

@end

@implementation AppDelegate


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    // Override point for customization after application launch.


    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];

    self.window.rootViewController = [[GraphViewController alloc] init];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}

...
```

### GraphViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "HomeViewController.h"

@interface GraphViewController : UIViewController <HomeViewControllerDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) HomeViewController *homeVC;

@property (nonatomic, assign) Float32 data;

@end
```

### GraphViewController.m

```
#import "GraphViewController.h"

@interface GraphViewController ()

@end

@implementation GraphViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor purpleColor];

    self.homeVC = [[HomeViewController alloc] init];
    self.homeVC.delegate = self;

    NSLog(@"presenting homeVC in 2 seconds...");

    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(2.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        [self presentViewController:self.homeVC animated:YES completion:^{
            NSLog(@"homeVC presented, you should get data in 3 seconds...");
        }];

    });
}

-(void)addItem:(Float32)item
{
    self.data = item;
    NSLog(@"Graph view data: %f", self.data);
}

@end
```

### HomeViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol HomeViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)addItem:(Float32)item;

@end




@interface HomeViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, weak) id<HomeViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

### HomeViewController.m

```
#import "HomeViewController.h"

@interface HomeViewController ()

@end

@implementation HomeViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.


    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    // --------------------------------------------------------
    // simulate a callback by executing code after 3 seconds
    // --------------------------------------------------------
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(3.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{


        // good thing comes in pairs :D
        [self.delegate addItem:2.0];



    });
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



@end
```

I got this in my console output:

```
2015-08-28 16:20:53.021 AudioCallbackDemo[6973:194320] presenting homeVC in 2 seconds...
2015-08-28 16:20:55.534 AudioCallbackDemo[6973:194320] homeVC presented, you should get data in 3 seconds...
2015-08-28 16:20:58.044 AudioCallbackDemo[6973:194320] Graph view data: 2.000000
```